# unistd.h file not found, clang++ and OS X

Tags: c++, emacs, header, clang++, unistd.h

I'm currently struggling with clang++, and after looking on the web for a long time I decided asking my question. I'm on OS X and using clang++ via Emacs (it's used by flycheck to highlight errors, among other things). I have a very simple file that starts with :

```
#include <iostream>
```

And the line is underlined in red. When I go check the clang logs, here's what I have :

```
In file included from ./point.hpp:4:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:23:10: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found
#include <unistd.h>
```

So, the error comes from the `iostream` include, and in `iostream` there's a `#include <unistd.h>` that clang++ doesn't like.

I'll say it immediately, I have Xcode AND the command-line tools installed. So my `unistd.h` should be there. My code also compiles (via g++), so everything is fine there. It's just clang++ that's lost.

Something I notice is that it's going in my llvm folder (that I installed with homebrew) to fetch `iostream`, that doesn't seem right. He should be getting the `iostream` in my system, right ? So `/usr/local/include/c++/iostream`. Could this be the problem ? If so, how can I tell it to get the right `iostream` ?

And if it's not the problem, how could I solve my `unistd.h` problem ?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT** : With the `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ image.cpp` command, I get this :

```
clang++ -stdlib=libc++ image.cpp
In file included from image.cpp:1:
In file included from ./image.hpp:4:
In file included from ./figure.hpp:4:
In file included from ./point.hpp:4:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:23:10: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found
#include <unistd.h>
         ^
1 error generated.`
```

So, same problem.

**EDIT 2** : I noticed `which clang++` would return `/usr/local/bin/clang++` , so I tried specifically using the Xcode clang++ and here's the result :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libc++ image.cpp
In file included from image.cpp:1:
In file included from ./image.hpp:4:
In file included from ./figure.hpp:4:
In file included from ./point.hpp:4:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:23:10: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file
  not found
#include <unistd.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

So same problem on the C++ headers bundled with XCode.

Comment: Could you solve the problem by yourself? If yes, any tips? I am currently struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Yup, I ended up finding a way. Actually, fully reinstalling Xcode and the command line tools didn't solve my problem because, for some reason, my Xcode installs buggy command line tools when installing them via its GUI. When I installed them using `xcode-select --install` in a terminal, it solved my clang issues.